# SEO, google crawl

Tags: java, seo, google-crawlers

I have implemented the pagination like below

```
http://myhost.com/product-2/213-1
```

Which means there are total 213 products and this is the first page.
When I check the what pages Google crawled in my website I see the result like

```
http://myhost.com/product-2/213-1-2/144-0/144-1/144-14/125-1/125-12/125-1/151-15/108-10/131-1/134-13/140-14/140-1/118-11/126-1/126-12/110-1/270-27/270-1/270-27
```

This means google is somehow appending all the page numbers at the end of the URL and crawling that URL. Could someone give me a solution to stop this? For this particular case I want Google to crawl only one page having all the product information.

Comment: I'd say this indicates that some of the links on your page don't do what you think they do.

Answer (score 1):

Use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to tell Google which page is the one page you want to show in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

That is weird. Looks like you are using relative links in your pagination and your URL-Router is accepting this somehow without throwing a 404... instead it is showing content because of interpreting only a part of the URL and not the whole. So search-engines can crawl this URLs.

Example:

You are linking to

```
next-side/
```

instead of

```
/path/to/next-side/
```

If you post a link the community can try out!

By the way I wouldn't recommend to change the URL by number of items. Using fixed URLs is much better and the number of items is of none interest. Better use something like /shop/category/subcategory/product .

Answer (score 0):

I will add to the great answers that they gave you that you can use the rel next\prev pagination elements.
To let google know that the next link is the next page in your list.

More information you can find on google webmaster blogs there is an [**post**](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html) and [**video tutorial**](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/video-about-pagination-with-relnext-and.html).

they both will explain you how to implement and use the pagination tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, I was thinking the same thing to use canonical or rel next\prev tags, but the problem here is the page is loaded by ajax so technically it is the same page. But yes, I will somehow find the possibility of using the rel next/prev in each pages and using canonical tags in view all pages. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If its technically the same page but in different address i recommend you to use the canonical tag